# std::optional<T> and functions taking a non-const reference to T

Tags: c++, c++11, option-type, c++17

Suppose I have a function

```
void set_value(MyType& x);
```

and I want to call it with a variable of type

```
std::experimental::optional<MyType> myvar
```

I can't simply call `set_value(*myvar)` since `myvar` might not have a value.  How can I safely ensure the result of `set_value()` on `myvar` in all cases?

I would like to avoid writing:

```
decltype(my_var)::value_type tmp;
set_value(tmp);
my_var = tmp;
```

Comment: No idea what you're asking. What is the relation between the `set_value()` function and the `optional`? What is `x`?

Comment: `std::experimetnal::optional<T>::value()` / `operator*` do return a reference.

Comment: @melak47: What happens if the optional doesn't have a value? Does it throw on that call?

Comment: @einpoklum So you want `set_value` to *populate* the value in `myvar`, regardless of whether or not it exists?

Comment: @Barry: Yes, but I see you've already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class F, class T>
decltype(auto) set_optional( F&& f, std::experimental::optional<T>& o ) {
  if (!o) o.emplace();
  return std::forward<F>(f)(*o);
}
```

now you can:

```
set_optional( set_value, myvar );
```

and it works.

Note, however, that a function taking a reference to `MyType` is expecting both an input and output parameter there.  Output-only parameters are returned.  Many people reuse that for output-only parameters.  This causes issues like what you run into above, and needless default construction.

```
set_value(*myvar);
```

You can do this inline:

```
if (!myvar) myvar.emplace();
set_value(*myvar);
```

where we construct it if empty, then use it.

Or, a different refactoring (which I think is nice):

```
template<class T, class...Args>
T& emplace_or( std::experimental::optional<T>& o, Args&&...args ) {
  if (!o) o.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return *o;
}
```

then:

```
set_value(emplace_or(myvar));
```

Or this final option:

```
set_value(void(!myvar?myvar.emplace(),void(),3:16),*myvar)
```

`void(),3:16`: For optional so loved "hello world" they gave it their one and only contents, that whomever believes it is engaged shall not segfault but have a correct program.

Comment: And nothing like set_optional and ensure_engaged is in the Lib Fundamentals TS? Seems like a `make_pair`-style useful utility to me.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm trying to make them behave a bit like `std::experimental::expected`'s monad helpers.  It isn't a great fit.  I'm unaware of any similar functionality.  Note I renamed `ensure_engaged` to `emplace_or` to match `value_or`.  As `emplace_or` mutates, it can return a `T&`.

Comment: Link to those monad helpers?

Comment: @einpoklum [`std::experimental::expected`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
if (!my_var) { my_var.emplace(); }
set_value(*my_var);
```

---

But the better way would be to simply be able to change the signature of `set_value` to be:

```
MyType set_value();
```

so that you could've just written:

```
my_var = set_value();
```

Input/Output parameters suck.

Comment: `set_value` is not under my control.that way, but an empty emplace is nice.